# Valgrind showing more frees than allocs

Tags: c++, valgrind

I ran valgrind on my program , it returned no memory leaks . However it shows more frees than allocs and im not really sure why .

Thanks in advance

```
==4234== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4234==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4234==   total heap usage: 304 allocs, 542 frees, 81,820 bytes allocated
==4234== 
==4234== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4234== 
==4234== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4234== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==4234== ERROR SUMMARY: 3555 errors from 13 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: You will need to show at least some of your code if you want us to help find the cause of this issue!

Comment: Possibly it is counting frees of nullptr values.

Comment: @AdrianMole I just dont know which part of the code is causing it , valgrind did not provide me with the line it has problems with

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm would that cause problems in my program in the future ?

Comment: Freeing a null pointer is fine and should not cause any problems.

Comment: You're probably going to have to work on making a minimal example.  Based on my quick and dirty test, `valgrind` on my system isn't counting `free(NULL)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check what addresses are getting allocated by using the `--trace-malloc=yes` option. I would advise against using it on a large application!

For instance, with this small application

```
int main()
{
   int* pi = new int;
   delete pi;
}
```

I get

```
paulf> ./vg-in-place --trace-malloc=yes ../vg_examples/noleak
==88971== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==88971== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==88971== Using Valgrind-3.16.0.GIT and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==88971== Command: ../vg_examples/noleak
==88971== 
--88971-- _Znwm(4) = 0x5800040
--88971-- _ZdlPv(0x5800040)
==88971== 
==88971== HEAP SUMMARY:
==88971==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==88971==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 4 bytes allocated
==88971== 
==88971== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==88971== 
==88971== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==88971== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

A couple of notes

1. You'll probably want to run `valgrind` rather than `vg-in-place`, unless you're building Valgrind yourself.
2. The function names are mangled. If you want to see the non-mangled names you can run

```
paulf>  ./vg-in-place --trace-malloc=yes ../vg_examples/noleak 2>&1 | /usr/bin/c++filt 

[snip]

--89034-- operator new(unsigned long)(4) = 0x5800040
--89034-- operator delete(void*)(0x5800040)
```